# php object array: can we add more associative keys into them?

Tags: php, arrays, object

If I do the following:

```
foreach ($extrasServices as $extras)
{
  var_dump($extras);
}
```

I got this:

```
object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["optionname"]=>
  string(16) "Disk Space"
  ["optiontype"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}

object(stdClass)#18 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["optionname"]=>
  string(22) "Database (MySQL)"
  ["optiontype"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}

object(stdClass)#19 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["optionname"]=>
  string(14) "Extra Domain"
  ["optiontype"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

On each of those object(stdClass) extras, I need to add an additional associative key, inside that associative key we should be able to store another array.

How can we accomplish something like this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really treat the array of objects that you're iterating over as what they are - objects - and use any setter method you have. (Or just set the property.)

As such:

```
foreach ($extrasServices as &$extras) {
    // If you've a custom setter.
    $extras->setterMethod('key', 'new value');

    // If you don't.
    $extras->key = 'new value';
}
```

However, you'll also **need to ensure that you're accessing the objects via reference** (otherwise they won't change outside of the foreach iterator). Hence the &$extras in the foreach statement in the above example.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how will that setter be coded? public function setSomething($something)
{
  $this->_something = $something;
} This is how I normally do. :s

Comment: I'm using value objects, so, a class with getters and setters, however, this object(class) is a php generated one, not mine. Not sure where to place it.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($extrasServices as $extras)
{
  $extras->new_key = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
  var_dump($extras);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jeroen. I will try the setter approach if I'm able to properly understand it. :)

Comment: @MEM I don´t use the `stdClass`, but it´s just an object and I don´t think it has a standard setter method but I guess you could extend it and add it if you wanted to...